# Create custom domain for each client in cloud application

Tags: architecture, cloud

I am working on an cloud application where individuals can register themselves. But I'm in confusion that how to create separate area for each and every individuals. I was looking for approach like creating a subdomain for each individual and have separate DB for them.

Please help....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you're talking about a SaaS (Software as a Service) kind of app. General answer as usual is that it depends upon the application type. It could be using either 1 database (or a set of databases) for all users or separate databases for each user.

Generally speaking though, separate databases/apps is a better solution for several reasons. For instance suppose user wants to have a backup of his data. Having all data in central database makes it hard to take backup separately. Performance could be another reason as well.

Another point is that different users may need different computing capacities. Say you're developing an app which is being used by a company with 20000 users working simultaneously, the CPU/Memory needed for such a client is different from a company with 5 users. So if your app is capable of being deployed separately for each client, they can setup their environment accordingly. They can also stop their computing services (Virtual Machines, Docker Containers, etc) and avoid cloud computing cost in case of not using the system.

Having said that, it's not a silver bullet, in some types of applications, a central app/db works better. If you give more details about the app, it would be much easier to judge about the better architecture.

Comment: Hi @akazemis, Sorry for very late reply. But basically working on an product  targeting enterprises. You can say that it is kind of ERP like system.

Comment: Hi @Shubham, I'd say it's definitely better to have separate DB and app instance per client for such a system. As I said you may need to scale up or scale out separately for each client. Using a single database and app instance forces lots of limits and makes your app design more complicated. Just isolate clients apps and keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, Currently what we have adopted is Single App and DB/Tenant. But the problem that we are facing issue is in rolling out the DB changes to every tenant. So what could be the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: you're welcome. There are different strategies for doing so. Canary deployment strategy is one of them. Google it you'll find some articles. here is Martin Fowler's brief article : https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html